# Voltage of inductor/transformer with a square wave input

Tags: transformer, inductor, waveform

I'm kind of having trouble thinking of what the response of an inductor to a square wave input would be, as well as the response of a transformer (I found this answer for a square wave input to a transformer a little incomplete or unclear: [Square Wave input into Transformer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/132115/square-wave-input-into-transformer)).  It's my understanding that the graphs for the current and voltage of an inductor when a circuit is closed are exponential shaped, so for a transformer with an idea square wave input (modeling the primary as an RL circuit) what will the output waveform be?  Would the output voltage be a exponential triangle wave, a square wave with the rising portion exponential portion, something else or am I not thinking of this right?

Comment: You should stipulate whether you're asking about *ideal* inductor/transformer circuits or not.  It's true that the current through a non-ideal inductor, for a square-wave voltage across, is segments of an exponential curve but that isn't the case for an ideal inductor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would the output voltage be a exponential triangle wave, a square wave
>   with the rising portion exponential portion, something else or am I
>   not thinking of this right?

If you ignored the resistance of the primary winding and used the standard formula for an inductor: -

$$V=L\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

And then applied a positive step voltage, you would get a rising ramp of current whose slope is V/L (as per the above formula).

When the square wave goes negative you get a falling ramp of current and the cycle repeats. That rising and falling current produces a rising and falling flux in the core.

Then, using the other well-known formula for transformers: -

$$V = N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}$$

We see that the output waveform from the secondary is also a square wave because the rate of change of flux is either a positive constant value or a negative constant value.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that formula.  That makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An inductor is integrating the applied voltage over time.

So, if the voltage is a positive constant, the current is a upwards ramp with constant grade. If the voltage is a negative constant, the current is a downwards ramp with constant grade. The current cannot "jump", it's continous.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  But they'll be exponential ramps?

Comment: @Tom, what is an exponential ramp?  Typically, a [ramp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function) is, e.g., a segment of a linear function of time.

Comment: Voltage where Vl=V(e^-(rt/l))

Comment: @Tom, for a square-wave voltage across an ideal inductor, the current through is [triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave), not exponential.  See, e.g., [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd8VV.png) --  [Image credit](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/voltage-and-current-phase-shifting-current-without-voltage.918816/page-2#post-5796717)

Comment: I added this to my answer.

Comment: To add to this, if you have an ideal inductor, then $$i_L(t)=\frac{1}{L}\int_0^t{v_L(\tau)d\tau}+i_0$$ with \$i_0\$ being the initial current through the inductor. If you were to integrate a square voltage, you get triangular currents.

Comment: I see.  I guess this is sort of part of my question, but what would generally make an inductor non-ideal?

Comment: Series resistance mainly. That would limit the current. For higher frequencies and currents, cross-winding capacitance will introduce self-oscillation.